This code works just fine, but I don't know why
I have some onEdit() code that writes the result in another tab just fine, I don't know how! How does createAbsenceAlert() know what cells have been edited and their value? I can't see how I'm passing it any variables.
const workBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

function onEdit(e) {
  var eventValue = e.value
  if (eventValue === "Absent" && e.range.getColumn() === 3) {
    var emailAbsenceDetails = createAbsenceAlert(); 
  }
  return;
};

function createAbsenceAlert() {
  var absentPerson = workBook.getSheetName();
  var vmsSender = workBook.getName()          // extract name of sender from file name
    .split(/\s+/)
    .slice(0, -2)  
    .join(" ");

  const editRecord = workBook.getSheetByName("editRecord");
  let trg = editRecord.getRange(3, 3).getDataRegion().getLastRow()

  // format date.
  let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric" })
  var absenceDetails = date + ": " + absentPerson + " has just been marked absent from " + vmsSender + "'s appointment";
     
  return absenceDetails
};

I should add, there are multiple tabs in the Google sheet, so it's not just looking at a single sheet.
There's other parts of the code that rely on my understanding what's going on here. Thanks all.

The onEdit() function does not do anything; it doesn't return a value and it doesn't modify anything. If something is "working" for your spreadsheets, it isn't that.

"How does createAbsenceAlert() know what cells have been edited" because it's called from the onEdit "and their value" because it looks up the values from the sheet. And they have already been edited.

@VLAZ Thanks, so createAbsenceAlert() is just looking at the active sheet in the absence of any other instruction? I originally added e in the param, but it just greyed out.

const workBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
That line takes the spreadsheet
When onEdit() runs and checks that the value is "Absent" and the column is 3, it runs createAbsenceAlert(). This function knows "where is it run from" because of the constant workBook of the first line, and .getSheetName() -in the context of a spreadsheet, without specifying which tab you want- is getting the name of the active sheet

Thanks. So the function is just grabbing the active sheet/cell and reading the value, despite my not passing those values to it?
I originally placed e as a variable in function parameters, but it just greyed out.
